# Como Abrir/Fechar vários Forms a partir de um Form Principal

Tags: delphi

Tenho um `FormPrincipal` o qual tem um `Tmenu` com `Tactionlist` e, a partir deste form quero chamar vários outros Forms, de acordo com os itens do menu.

No form principal, tenho um `Panel` e quero que os outros forms abram dentro deste panel.

Ajustei o código abaixo, após ajuda de outros colegas do StackOverflow em inglês, e funcionou:

```
procedure TFormPrincipal.AbreFormBancoExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin   
  Formbanco := Tformbanco.Create(Self);
  Formbanco.Parent := PanelCorpo;
  Formbanco.Align := alclient;
  Formbanco.BorderIcons := [];
  Formbanco.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Formbanco.Show;
end;
```

Porém agora preciso saber qual formulário está ativo no Panel para poder fechá-lo assim que fechar o outro, ou seja, preciso modificar a rotina acima :

```
procedure TFormPrincipal.AbreFormBancoExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin   

  // identificar qual form está ativo dentro do FormPrincipal
  // fechar este form e em seguida rodar o código abaixo  
  Formbanco := Tformbanco.Create(Self);
  Formbanco.Parent := PanelCorpo;
  Formbanco.Align := alclient;
  Formbanco.BorderIcons := [];
  Formbanco.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Formbanco.Show;
end;
```

Esta é uma boa abordagem para tratar as chamadas de Forms a partir de um form principal correta?

. **Ajuste no código para obter o form aberto no momento**. No Formbanco coloquei o seguinte :

```
procedure TFormbanco.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin     
  Edit1.text := Screen.Activeform.Name;  // não mostra Formbanco !!  
                                             // só mostra FormPrincipal !!
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considere esse exemplo:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  vForm1 := TForm.Create(Self);
  vForm1.Parent := Panel1;
  vForm1.Width := 100;
  vForm1.Align := alLeft;
  vForm1.Name := 'Form1Teste1';
  vForm1.Show;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  vForm2 := TForm.Create(Self);
  vForm2.Parent := Panel1;
  vForm2.Width := 100;
  vForm2.Align := alLeft;
  vForm2.Name := 'Form1Teste2';
  vForm2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Assigned(vForm1)) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('1 esta criado');
  end;

  if (Assigned(vForm2)) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('2 esta criado');
  end;
end;
```

Sendo vForm1 e vForm2 respectivamente variáveis do tipo `TForm` que você substituiria pelos próprios formulários!

`if Assigned()` Testa se um objeto foi assinado, ou seja, se ocorreu a criação, se existe. O Resultado é um booleano.

Você também pode testar se o objeto é diferente de `nil` que também funcionaria.
No caso você criaria um função para validar se o formulário já foi criado, dessa forma evitaria a redundância de código que deixei no exemplo (Button3Click)!

Comment: Junior, obrigado. Mas ainda tenho uma dúvida, pois o ponto principal é saber qual forms está aberto na tela, com o foco nele,  no momento que vou abrir um outro forms. Preciso achar este forms aberto antes de abrir um novo com o Button1 ou Button2 acima. O if Assigned() me diz qual está aberto no momento?

Comment: Vou modificar a resposta complementando... Para o caso vamos percorrer os componentes Filhos do Panel para saber quais são formulários e quais fechar!

Comment: Porque não criar uma simples variavel com o ultimo form carregado?

Comment: Na verdade a melhor opção para ele é um `ShowModal`, vamos esperar a reação dele ao ler aqui.

Comment: Junio e Tiago, obrigado.   no código acima, ao substituir Form.Show or Form.showmodal a aplicação fica travada após pressionar o Button2, pois abre o Form2 mas não mudo o foco para ele e nem volta ao Form1 principal !     Tiago, pensei e usar esta variavel para guardar o ultimo form carregado, foi por isso que pedi ajuda para obter o nome do form visible no momento. Ajustei o código, colocando no evento OnShow do forms que foi aberto  Edit1.text := Screen.Activeform.Name , MAS NÃO FUNCIONOU, pois sempre mantém o nome do form Principal !!

Comment: Pessoal, agradeço se puderem ver meu último código.

Answer (score 1):

Junior e Tiago, fiz um ajuste no código e consegui o comportamento desejado. Porém a procedure CloseActiveForm(Forname : String) , a qual recebe o nome do forms e executa um FreeAndNil(form) no forms correspondente está muito hard-coded ! Observem que no código para obter o form a ser fechado está com vários IFs. Creio que deva haver uma forma melhor e obter o form (variavel form). Podem me ajudar nisso ?

**O Programa**
Há 3 forms  sendo o form1 o principal que chamará o form2 e form3 que serão abertos num panel no form1.  Assim que o form2 ou form3 são abertos, mostro o nome do form aberto e tenho um botao Check Active que retorna Screen.ActiveForm.Name

**Form1 - Principal**
...

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses unit2, unit3;


procedure Tform1.CloseActiveForm (Formname : string);
// Free memory allocated to the current form , set it to nil
// I'll have to find a better way to perform FreeanNil without
// use many IFs command
begin
     if Formname  = 'form2' then FreeAndnil(Form2) else
         if Formname = 'form3' then FreeandNil(Form3);
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
       CloseActiveForm(Edit1.Text); //Edit1 has the current active form name
       if form2 = nil  then
        begin
              Application.CreateForm(Tform2,Form2);
              Form2.Parent  := Panel1;
              Form2.Align   := alclient;

              Form2.Show;
              Form2.BorderStyle :=  bsnone;
              Form2.SetFocus;
              Form2.OnActivate(Sender);   //Method Show blocks Activate event
        //    Showmessage('Form2 is  Nil');
        end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
       CloseActiveForm(Edit1.Text); //Edit1 has the current active form name
       if form3 = nil  then
        begin
              Application.CreateForm(Tform3,Form3);
              Form3.Parent  := Panel1;
              Form3.Align   := alclient;

              Form3.Show;
              Form3.BorderStyle := bsnone;
              Form3.SetFocus;
              Form3.OnActivate(Sender);  //Method Show blocks Activate event
          //  Showmessage('Form3 is Nil');
        end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Edit1.Text := Screen.ActiveForm.Name;
end;
end.
```

**Form2  (igual form3)**

```
... 
   var
      Form2: TForm2;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}
    uses unit1;

    procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
           Edit2.Text := Screen.ActiveForm.Name;
    end;

    procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
         setfocus;
         Edit1.Text       := Form2.Name;
         Form1.Edit1.Text := Form2.Name;

    // a propriedade Screen.ActiveForm.Name se for usada trará
    // sempre o nome do Form1 - principal, porque este forms aqui
    // está com o Parent setado omo Painel1 do Forms 1 !!
    end;

    end.
```

**Telas do programa**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]